# Heavy tailed distributions and their sum

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions, distribution-tails

Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be the sequence of i.i.d random variables with heavvy tailed distributions, i.e. 
$$p(x_{i}) \sim \frac{A}{x_{i}^{\alpha}}$$ 
as $x_{i} \rightarrow \infty$, where $p(x_{i})$ stands for the density of $X_{i}$.

The question is: how to estimate the asymtotic of the density $p(y)$, where $$Y = X_{1} + X_{2} + \ldots + X_{n}$$ ?

A pretty straightforward approach is the following: calculate the characteristic function of $X_{i}$, since the random variables are i.i.d, then $$\varphi_{Y}(t) = \varphi_{X_{1} + X_{2} + \ldots + X_{n}}(t) = (\varphi_{X_{1}}(t))^{n}$$ then apply the inverse Fourier transform to figure out the distribution of sum.

Are there any, say, 'elegant' ways to approach the problem above?

Comment: If you are looking for asymptotics for regularly varying distribution, see Feller, W. (1971) An Introduction to Probability Theory and Its Applications. Vol. II. Second edition. Wiley, New York, p.278. Russian edition 1984 p.319. Or Embrechts, P., Kluppelberg, C. and Mikosch, T. (1997) Modelling Extremal Events for Insurance and Finance. Springer, Berlin, Lemma 1.3.1. 

If you are asking about heavy-tailed indeed (more general than regularly varying), look at S.Foss, D.Korshunov, S.Zachary, An Introduction to Heavy-tailed and Subexponential Distributions, Springer, 2011, 2012, Theorem 2.12.